# How to prevent XSS in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, xss, security, cross-site

What are the techniques that one can use to prevent cross site scripting in asp.net? Are there any non ready implementations that one can use to achieve a website protected against xss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did in-house development for this purpose for a long time, but finally Microsoft provided a library for it. We now replaced our library with this one completely. It can simply be used as follows:

```
string sanitizedString = Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(string myStringToBeChecked);
```

The only problem with this method is that it trims multiple whitespaces that are separated with line ending characters. If you do not want that to happen, you may consider splitting the string first with respect to line ending characters (\r\n), then calculate the number of whitespaces before and after these splitted strings, apply sanitizer, append whitespaces back and concatenate.

Other than that, Microsoft library works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, AntiXSS.GetSafeHtmlFragment() turned to be vulnerable in older versions and useless in newest version (v. 4.2.1) - it now strips almost all HTML tags possible and became unusable :(

Answer (score 1):

The microsoft anti cross site scripting library is a good start. It has some useful helper methods to prevent XSS. It is now part of the larger [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**To protect cross site scripting attack as following ways.**

```
 1.  Use HtmlEncoding while saving the input content that is received from web  application controls usch as textbox etc.
 2.  Use InnerText instead of InnerHtml while displaying data on the page.
 3.  Do the input sanitization before saving the data into database.
```